# Introducir valores de un <select> php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un select que coge datos de la tabla propietario_procesos. La tabla propietario procesos tiene lod campos: "id_proceso", "nombre_propietario", "procesoE".

Este es el select:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['prop'])){
    $mysqli->query("
        UPDATE Formulario
            SET id_proceso = (
                SELECT id_proceso 
                    FROM propietario_procesos
                    WHERE id_proceso = '(".($_POST['prop']*1).")'
            )
            WHERE id=(".($_POST['prop']*1).");
    ");
    // enviar aquí el correspondiente email
}

$query = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT * FROM propietario_procesos;
");

while($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_proceso'].'">'
        .$valores['nombre_propietario'].' - '
        .$valores['ProcesoE']
        .'</option>';
}
?>
```

Los datos del select los tengo que introducir en la tabla formulario utilizando un update. La tabla formulario contiene: "id", email, "fecha_creacion", "id_proceso", "nombre_propietario".

Cuando se selecciona el  Registrar, quiero que introduzca los datos de la tabla propietario de procesos en el correspondiente formulario (Dependiendo del id que tenga el formulario).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo que tu `UPDATE` lo complementes con un `JOIN` en vez de con un `WHERE`. Sería algo así:

```
UPDATE formulario f JOIN propietario_procesos p
  ON f.id=p.id_proceso
  SET f.id_proceso=p.id_proceso,
  f.nombre_propietario=p.nombre_propietario,
  f.email=p.email
  WHERE id = ".($_POST['prop']*1).";
```

El dataset para las comprobaciones sería:

```
CREATE TABLE propietario_procesos(
  id_proceso int,
  nombre_propietario varchar(31),
  ProcesoE int,
  email varchar(63)
  );
CREATE TABLE formulario(
  id int,
  email varchar(63),
  fecha_creacion datetime,
  id_proceso int,
  nombre_propietario varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO propietario_procesos
  (id_proceso, nombre_propietario, ProcesoE,email)
  VALUE
  (1,'P1',1,'email1@mail.com'),
  (2,'P2',2,'email2@mail.com');
INSERT INTO formulario (id) VALUES (1);
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios